# Maven artifact of same project failed

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project with following structure

```
/app
  /- pom.xml
  /- app-api
    /- pom.xml
  /- app-impl
    /- pom.xml
```

There are some external dependencies, but when I tried to build the project Maven failed while trying to retrieve app-api from external source with error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app-impl: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project com.examp:app-impl:jar:0.0.0.1: Could not
>   transfer artifact com.example:app-api:jar:0.0.0.1 from/to
>   nexus-snapshot (http://example.com/repository/snapshot): Failed to
>   transfer file:
>   http://example.com/repository/snapshot/com/example/app-api/0.0.0.1/app-api-0.0.0.1.jar.
>   Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Request. -> [Help 1]

The snapshot repository policies forbid 4 digit version. But I cannot understand why Maven does not associate that dependency locally.

Comment: First there is no limit in digits for versions and not related to SNAPSHOT's nor releases. Furthermore The error 400 means this artifacts has already been deployed into the repository...That means you are trying to do a `mvn deploy`....

Comment: @khmarbaise I could also be possible that the OP configured a Snapshot repository as Release repository in the distributionManagement

Comment: @khmarbaise It was a policy in nexus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the desired artifact is in your local repository (`.m2/repository`), Maven should find it there (without looking in remote repositories).
2. Otherwise, have a look at your `settings.xml` and see whether you misconfigured your repositories.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, my task ignores packaging api module. Rebuilding the whole project helps.